# A set which satisfies all conditions for a Group except associativity

Tags: group-theory

I have a question which I can't seem to prove or dismiss.

Can a set of elements A satisfy al the conditions for a group except associativity (which leaves us with closure, identity and invertibility).

Tried to prove it but can't seem to make a table which fullfiles these actions.

Thank you.

Comment: Subtraction.${}$

Comment: Since there are different sets of axioms of groups (which are equivalent as long as associativity is given, but not without associativity) you should make precise what you mean with "all" the conditions.

Comment: Just make the product of any two nonidentity elements equal the identity.

Comment: Also, you might want to look up the [Octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonions).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393453/non-associative-version-of-a-group-satisfying-these-identities-xyy-1-y

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Take the integers under subtraction.

(Note: This is a hint, not a solution. You need to alter it slightly to get an identity, as $x-0=x$ but $0-x=-x$.)

Comment: But what is the identity?

Comment: Yet $0 - x = x$ if and only if $x = 0$

Comment: @m.k. I have removed my last comment and undone my edit - I had forgotten that it was meant to be a hint!

Answer (score 3):

Such sets are called *loops*, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(mathematics)

Comment: A loop is not required to have two-sided inverses.

Comment: @m. k.: "which leaves us with closure, identity and invertibility" - I don't see two-sided inverses here!

Comment: @m. k.: Apropos, there are commutative loops, i.e. having two-sided inverses.