# Examples of loops which have two-sided inverses.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, grouplike-elements

Are there any neat examples of non-associative [loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loop) such that for each element a in the loop there exists $a^{-1}$ so that $a*a^{-1}=1=a^{-1}*a$.  Even cooler would be a commutative loop. Also: are there commutative finite loops?

Comment: yes, do you know any finite order examples or commutative?

Comment: It looks like the unit octonions form a finite example.

Comment: I put a bunch of information on inverses in quasi-groups at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393453/non-associative-version-of-a-group-satisfying-these-identities-xyy-1-y/393913#393913 Most of it is specifically geared to not having an identity, but you might still find it interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also the [Parker Loop](http://www.timhsu.net/pdf/tp.pdf) which is a finite loop of order $2^{13}$ related to the binary Golay code, $M_{24}$ (largest sporadic Mathieu group), Conway's construction of the Monster group, etc.

Comment: I can't see your link

Comment: @Ted Hi! The link may be obsolete again!

Answer (score 3):

I think most of your questions are answered by looking at [Moufang loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop).

A loop in which the left and right inverse agree (a loop with two-sided inverses) is called an IP-loop. Sometimes people replace a loop by an [isotope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopy_of_loops), which basically scrambles and relabels the multiplication table (apply a row and column permutation, and a permutation of the underlying set). For groups, that would basically be crazy, but loops are not terribly messed up by such an operation.

A loop is a Moufang loop iff every isotope has two-sided inverses.

Non-associative, commutative, Moufang loops have order a multiple of 81, and there are two non-isomorphic such loops. They were constructed by M. Hall Jr.

Comment: The two non-associative commutative moufang loops of order 81 are available in GAP as `LoadPackage("loops");m1:=MoufangLoop(81,1);m2:=MoufangLoop(81,2);` I haven't seen a concise description of them, but I believe one exists.

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw an example from [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.14716) that I think is pretty neat. It's an abelian loop of infinite order.

Let $S$ be the set consisting of $1$ and all odd prime numbers. Define an operation $\cdot$ on $S$ where $a \cdot b$ gives the smallest element of $S$ strictly larger than $\lvert a - b \rvert$.

Clearly this operation is commutative and closed. The identity is given by $1$ and every element is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

[Zassenhaus's Commutative Moufang Loop](http://books.google.it/books?id=i5SlbIA-KwUC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=zassenhaus+commutative+moufang+loop&source=bl&ots=GCTnxHj-Lz&sig=tjmYtOfrftkn_J-AGaeO3zYaNSo&hl=it&sa=X&ei=0bhZU93zH7Og7Aai54BA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=zassenhaus%20commutative%20moufang%20loop&f=false) is an example of commutative loop of order $81$ which is not a group.