# Is group associativity equivalent to assuming equivalence of left and right inverses?

Tags: group-theory

Associativity is usually taken as one of the axioms that define a group, however I'm sure I recall reading that it can instead be proved if it is taken as axiomatic that the left and right inverses are the same.  In other words, given a set, $G$, and a binary relation, $\cdot$, can we prove that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot(b\cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c \in G$ from the following axioms?

- **Closure**:  $a\cdot b \in G$ for all $a, b \in G$, .
- **Identity**:  There exists a unique element $e \in G$ such that $e\cdot a = a\cdot e = a$ for all $x \in G$.
- **Inverses**:  For all $x \in G$, there exists a unique element $x^{-1} \in G$ such that $x\cdot x^{-1} = x^{-1}\cdot x = e$.

If not, am I misremembering and is there similar axiom that allows associativity to be proved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. The natural numbers under the Euclidean metric, $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ where $d(a, b)=|b-a|$, is a counter-example.

Identity is $0$, as $d(n, 0)=|n-0|=n$ and $d(0, n)=|0-n|=n$.

Inverse of $n$ is $n$, as $d(n, n)=|n-n|=0$.

It is non-associative as, for example, $0=d(1, 1)=d(1, d(2,3))\neq d(d(1,2), 3)=d(1, 3)=2$.

---

Thanks to lulu for spotting an issue with a previous version!

Answer (score 8):

A small counter-example is the set $G=\{e,a,b\}$ with a
binary operation $\,\cdot\,$ where
$$ e\cdot x=x\cdot e=x\cdot x=x \;\; \text{ for all }\;\;
 x\in G$$ while $a\cdot b=b\cdot a=e$.

Verify that it satisfies closure, identity, and inverses axioms.
Now consider

$$ a\cdot(b\cdot b)=a\cdot b = e \ne (a\cdot b)\cdot b = e\cdot b = b$$

which implies that the
[magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra))
$(G,\cdot)$ is not associative but it is idempotent
and commutative.

The operation table is
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\cdot & e & a & b \\ \hline
  e  & e & a & b \\ \hline
  a  & a & a & e \\ \hline
  b  & b & e & b \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

[**Edit** Jun 26, 2003] Actually, more is true. That is, using the same
set $G=\{e,a,b\}$ with a closed binary operation $\,\cdot\,$ where
$\, e\cdot x = x\cdot e = x\,$  for all $\, x\in G \,$ and either
$\, a\cdot a = b\cdot b = e\,$ **or**$\, a\cdot b = b\cdot a = e,\,$
then the binary operator $\,\cdot\,$
is associative if and only if $\, a\cdot b = b\cdot a = e,$
$a\cdot a = b,\,$ $b\cdot b = a\,$ (cyclic group). In only one
case out of eight is the operation associative.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very straightforward example.  I guess it's because I'm not used to thinking about non-associative structures, but that idempotent binary operator feels really weird.

Answer (score 2):

No.

> **Definition:** A [*loop*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) is a set $L$ with a binary operation $\ast$ such that
>
> - There is an identity element $1_L$ in $L$ with respect to $\ast$.
> - For all $a,b\in L$, there exist $x,y\in L$ with $$\begin{align} a\ast x&=b,\\ y\ast a&=b.\end{align}$$

A loop need not be associative. (Consider the [octonions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).)

You can check whether a loop has left and right inverses (that need not be the same).

> Let $a\in L$ be arbitrary and let $b=1_L$ in the above.

For examples of loops with two-sided inverses, see here:

[Examples of loops which have two-sided inverses.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619891/104041)

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question.  Yes, a loop is not a group, but as you say, a loop has distinct left and right inverses.  My question could have been phrased,'Is a loop whose left and right inverses are the same necessarily a group?'  The answer is no as others have pointed out, but I don't think your answer says this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have added a link to a question that covers loops with unique inverses, @richard.

Comment: Besides, octonions fit the bill.